# Capturing SQL Statistics Time In A Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I would like to do some automated SQL Profiling of some advanced queries through a large range of variable options.  What I'm hoping to do is something similar to the following

```
set statistics io on
set statistics time on

select *
from MyTable

set statistics time off
set statistics io off

--Somehow return the statistics for this query back to the calling C# code
-- so that I can log it for displaying in a report among other queries
```

I have tried using the following however I'm unsure of how to find the Query handle for my ran query to extract out the desired execution times

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
```

So really my question has 2 solutions. 1) Is it posible to simply capture the statistcs return message? 2) Or is it possible to find out my sql query handle so that I can query the dm_exec_query_stats table?

I should also mention I have considered doing the following but I'm hoping for a more complete solution.

```
declare @StartTime datetime = getdate();
Select * from myTable;
declare @Dur datetime = getdate() - @StartTime;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I turn to stackoverflow I figure it out myself!

In case anyone in the future is looking for this as well...Here is a solution where you simply enter your ran query in the where clause and all of the performance metrics are returned.  Please keep in mind that the times are in microseconds not milliseconds

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
where st.text = 'Your Query Here'
```